# Foreign Exchange Fallacy

Tags: probability, finance

Suppose that:

1. \$1 is worth €1 now;
2. For next year, there's 50% chance that \$1 is worth €1.25 and 50% chance that \$1 is worth €0.8.

Then the expected value of \$1 in terms of euros is 1.025. However, the expected value of €1 in terms of dollars is also 1.025. This seems to be saying that dollar is expected to be both appreciating and depreciating. How is it even possible?

Comment: Saying the expected value of the US dollar is $1.025$ euros does not say that the US dollar is expected to be appreciating. It is felt to be equally likely to appreciate as to depreciate.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siegel%27s_paradox